# I want a div to be higher on the z axis than it's siblings, but its not seeming to work

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to have .footerdiv go on top of .tr2, and z-axis isn't doing the trick.  My apologies if my code is messy, I'm super new and its my first post here. Any and all suggestions are greatly appreciated.

The ultimate goal is that .tr1, .tr2 and .tr3 will all act as links in the form of triangular images, with .footerdiv acting as a menu of sorts. There's still a lot of work to go but this is the part I'm most stuck on.

```css
.triOption {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 40em; height: 27em;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.tr{
  width:40%;
  padding-bottom:28.2842712474619%;
  position:absolute;
  overflow:hidden;
  transform-origin:0 100%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
 z-index: -11;
}



.tr:before{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  top:0; left:0;
  width:100%; height:100%;
  background-image: url('https://earthjustice.org/sites/default/files/styles/image_800x600/public/mexican-gray-wolf_don-burkett-800.jpg?itok=LadqU1Ws');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center top;
  transform-origin:0 100%;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
 z-index: -11;
}



.tr2{
  width:40%;
  padding-bottom:28.2842712474619%;
  position:absolute;
  overflow:hidden;
  transform-origin:0% 100%;
  transform: rotate(360deg);
 z-index: -11;
}


.tr2:before{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  top:0; left:0;
  width:100%; height:100%;
  background-image: url('https://static.wixstatic.com/media/0f91d3_403873a7f0764e64962d334fba013197~mv2_d_5184_3456_s_4_2.jpg/v1/fill/w_449,h_412,al_c,q_80,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01/0f91d3_403873a7f0764e64962d334fba013197~mv2_d_5184_3456_s_4_2.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center top;
  transform-origin:0 100%;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
 z-index: -11;
}


.tr3{
  width:40%;
  padding-bottom:28.2842712474619%; 
  position:absolute;
  overflow:hidden;
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
 z-index: -11;
}




.tr3:before{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  top:0; left:0;
  width:100%; height:100%;
  background-image: url('http://cdn.akc.org/content/article-body-image/housetrain_adult_dog_hero.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center top;
  transform-origin:100% 100%;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
 z-index: -11;
}

.footerdiv{
 background-image: url('https://earthjustice.org/sites/default/files/styles/image_800x600/public/mexican-gray-wolf_don-burkett-800.jpg?itok=LadqU1Ws');
  top:0; left:0;
 position:absolute;
  width:100%; height:100%;
 transform-origin:39.8% 135.2%;
 transform: rotate(-45deg);
 z-index: 11;

 }
```

```html
<div class='triOption'>

 <a href='http://localhost/wordpress/2018/05/07/hey-baby-hey-baby-hey/#comment-2' class='tr' >
  <a href='http://localhost/wordpress/2018/05/07/morehousemusic/#comment-4' class='tr2' >
    <a href='http://localhost/wordpress/2018/05/07/hey-right-back/#comment-3' class='tr3' >
 <div class="footerdiv"> </div>

</div>
```

And finally here's what it looks like currently. [Triangle Links and bottom div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkZ7k.png)

Comment: i think negative z-index may be the problem. You should give positive values to tr3 just less than footerdiv

Comment: Just tried now. Solid idea but it didn't work :(

Comment: Could you please confirm what exactly you are trying to do. You want footerDiv on top and then under it tr3?

Comment: I just wanted footerdiv to be above tr1 2 and 3 on the z axis. I switched their order in the HTML however and that worked for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

I put footerdiv above the tr's in the HTML and that seems to have done the trick after some resizing.

```html
<div class='triOption'>

 <div class="footerdiv"> </div>
 <a href='http://localhost/wordpress/2018/05/07/hey-baby-hey-baby-hey/#comment-2' class='tr' >
  <a href='http://localhost/wordpress/2018/05/07/morehousemusic/#comment-4' class='tr2' >
    <a href='http://localhost/wordpress/2018/05/07/hey-right-back/#comment-3' class='tr3' >


</div>
```

Here's the
[end result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzEXP.png)
of the "fixed" code.